# What is `delegate` in a Rails form object file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a ruby form object, `xForm` that inherits from `Form`.

```
class xForm < Form
  # code
end
```

There is a section inside the form file called `# Delegations`

```
delegate :id, :xyz,
         :email, :email=,
         ...
         to: :user
```

I haven't dealt with form objects or delegations before, and wasn't able to find information by searching Google.

Can anyone explain what they are used for on a high-level?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873591/how-rails-delegate-method-works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegate is used if you want to easily access a value on an associated object

In your example, your Form has a user. In order to access email, you could continually type: `my_form.user.email` or you could use delegation (as in your example) which means you can just type `my_form.email` and the form figures out where to get the email from.

It allows you to reduce typing, but also to hide away implementation-details.

http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate explains it pretty well if you want more

Typically this is used for Form objects so that you can build a flatter params-structure in the view that contains the form. eg if you delegate both `:email` and `:email=` then you can name a field `:email` in the `my_form` form... and then in the controller you can just use `my_form = MyForm.new(params[:my_form])` instead of having to separately instantiate the associated objects and pass the attributes specific to each.

Comment: Does the 2nd `:email=` add anything or just `:email` would do the same thing?

Comment: The difference between the two is `:email=` is a writer by convention, while `:email` is a reader. It means by convention if you want to change the value of a property, you can use the writer as such: `my_form.email='chris@so.com'` while in order to read the value, you'd do `my_form.email # ()=> 'chris@so.com'`. Remember, I said by convention, because you could also choose to do it in any other way.

Comment: As @oreoluwa says - it allows you to use the write as well as the reader. What typically this means is that you can add an email field on the form in the view and then pass params into the form as `form.new(params)` - I might add this to my answer.